# Eclipse HTTP Listener to run Internal Plugin in Headless Mode

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty, osgi

I have an Eclipse plugin that my company uses to analyze some data files. I've been tasked with writing a REST application that will take uploaded data files and use this plugin to generate some output and return it to the client. 
Currently, my application listens for incoming requests and launches Eclipse in Headless Mode to startup this plugin (e.g. ./eclipse -application "xyz" ...) .
The trouble is, Eclipse is fairly slow to start and each request received launches a new instance of Eclipse.

Ideally, I want only one instance of Eclipse running all the time and an HTTP listener that can request this plugin to run.

I looked into something like Jetty, but my understanding is that Jetty needs to be embedded in the plugin code to setup a listener. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the plugin's source code.

Is this possible? Which tools would you use?

Comment: Why listen for requests yourself?  Can you not just have embedded-jetty do the listening, request dispatching, and responding for you?

Comment: I would like to! I don't think I can embed the Jetty though - I don't have the source code for this plugin. Have I misunderstood you? Can Jetty be used outside of an application in the same capacity?